# Calculating Grades in SQL

Tags: sql

Very simply, I need to find student grades using SQL.
If, for example, I have following table that define grades

```
Marks (int)
Grade (Char)
```

and the data like this:

```
Marks | Grade

__90 | A+

__80 | A

__70 | A-

__60 | B

__50 | C

__40 | D
```

Okay, having said that, if I have a student that gained marks 73, how do I calculate her grade using above gradings in SQL.

Thank you so much...

Comment: is this homework?  if so, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Richard Friend's answer seems to be the one that actually answers the question as asked.  You should look at switching the accepted answer to that one.  The current accepted answer says that it didn't answer your question in the first sentence.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since I didn't find any way to do it using MySQL, I had to do some PHP programming to achieve the result. The goal is to get the closest value from gradings.

Okay suppose, we have the grades as defined in my question.

```
$MarksObt = 73 <- Marks obtained by the student:
```

Step 1: Get grades from mysql ordered by Marks in ASC order (ASC order is important):

```
SELECT marks, grade FROM gradings ORDER BY marks
```

Step 2: Create an array variable "$MinGrades". Loop through the result of above query. Suppose MySQL results are stored in "$Gradings" array. Now on each iteration, do the following:

1. Subtract the **$Grading['marks']** From $MarksObt
2. If result is greater than or equal to 0, add the result to "$MinGrades" array

Step 3: When loop ends, the "$MinGrades" array's first element will be the closest value ... DONE

Below is the PHP code that implements the above:

```
$MinGrades = array();

foreach($Gradings as $Key=>$Grading){
    $Subtract = $MarksObt - $Grading['marks'];
    if( $Subtract >= 0 )
        array_push($MinGrades, array($Key=>$Subtract))
}

$GradeKey = key($MinGrades[0]); // Get key of first element in the array
print $Gradings[$GradeKey]['grade'];
```

If you have some better approach, please mention here.
Thanks for your contribution...

Answer (score 7):

You want the highest value below or equal to your value, substitue 73 for your value...

`select top 1 Grade from TableName where Mark <= 73 order by Mark desc`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `GradeCutoff` table is created with something like:

```
CREATE TABLE GradeCutoff
  ( mark int
  , grade char(3)
  )
```

and you want to check `@studentMark`

```
SELECT grade
FROM GradeCutoff
WHERE mark =
   ( SELECT max(mark)
     FROM gradeCutoff
     WHERE @studentMark >= mark
   )
;
```

*Note:* you may also have to add a (0, 'E') row in your cutoff table.

Comment: This wont work since "=" does not work if the second select statement returns more than 1 rows.

Comment: @D3: the subqery will return exactly one row (a mark or `NULL`).

Comment: If i have a mark of 41 i will get a C? that jumps up to the next grade, i would of thought `SELECT max(mark)
     FROM gradeCutoff
     WHERE mark <= @studentMark`

Answer (score -1):

`SELECT Grade FROM 'table name here' WHERE student_mark  <= 79 AND student_mark >= 70` - in order to be more specific I would need to see the actual layout of the tables. But, something to that affect would work.

Comment: That wouldnt return any rows.. no values in that table between 70 and 80

Comment: I must be confused then. Is there two tables or one? In grading apps I have developed before, there was a reference tabl that defined what score got what grade, and then the students table, that had the scores in it. Thats what im using as a reference. If there is only one table, then know, this will not work.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should define a UDF for this which takes student markes as parameter and returns the grade according to the table given.

Then you can get grade for any student from student table as -

```
select studentID, getGrade(studentMarks) from student
```

Here `getGrade(studentMarks)` is UDF and `studentMarks` is column in student table with marks (for eg: in your case it is 73)

**HINT**: You need to use `CASE` construct in the UDF to get the grade.

Answer (score -2):

If the marks are actually regular multiples of 10, you could look into SQLs MOD function

Comment: no, marks can be any. User/Teacher can change them if required. So I need a general function that takes input from the Grades table and produce student grade.
Actually we need to calculate nearest value that I don't know how!